# Query target conditions

Tags: sql, presto

I need to query a table accounting for multiple change events. The table (*seen below*) is partitioned by `Date` where a snapshot of is taken every day of employees. I would like to create a table that shows milestone changes.

Namely I want the final export to show:

1. First Date they appear (*hire date*)
2. Any record when the `Type` changes
3. Last Date they appear (*termination date*)

This ultimately shows the changes in Type along with the hire/termination date.

I'm wondering what a good way to build this is? I can see a query that takes the `UNION` of the 3 criteria listed above and then sorts by date then employee but am not sure if this is efficient.

---

### Table

```
+-----------+------+----------+--------+
| Employee  | Type | Date     | Active |
+-----------+------+----------+--------+
| urdearboy | 1    | 1/1/2019 | 1      |    '<---- Want
+-----------+------+----------+--------+
| urdearboy | 1    | 1/2/2019 | 1      |
+-----------+------+----------+--------+
| urdearboy | 4    | 1/3/2019 | 1      |    '<---- Want
+-----------+------+----------+--------+
| urdearboy | 4    | 1/4/2019 | 1      |
+-----------+------+----------+--------+
| urdearboy | 4    | 1/5/2019 | 1      |
+-----------+------+----------+--------+
| urdearboy | 4    | 1/6/2019 | 1      |
+-----------+------+----------+--------+
| urdearboy | 4    | 1/7/2019 | 0      |    '<---- Want
+-----------+------+----------+--------+
```

In the above it can be deduced I was:

- Hired 1/1/19
- Changed Type 1/3/19
- Terminated 1/7/19

Answer (score 0):

One method is to use `lag()`:

```
select t.*
from (select t.*, 
             lag(date) over (partition by employee, type, active order by prev_date) as prev_date_eta,
             lag(date) over (partition by employee order by date) as prev_date
      from t
     ) t
where prev_date_eta is null or
      prev_date_eta <> prev_date;
```

This approach compares the previous date *with the same attributes* to the overall previous date for the employee.  When these are the same, nothing has changed, so the row is filtered out.

The use of `partition by` is a big convenience when you want to compare multiple columns.  The alternative is basically to compare each column individually.